# Google Play Services Issue

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

So we have a rather odd problem. The test APK of game opens the Google Play sign-in interface normally, you can select your account, and it acquires your user data and logs you in. Everything works perfectly; achievements, leaderboards, etc. This APK is, of course, installed directly on our test devices outside of the Google Play store.

However, when it is uploaded to Google Play and acquired through the store, the Google Play functionality seems to stop working correctly. Most times you can still sign into Google Play through the little pop-up window but nothing else works. No achievements, leaderboards, nothing. And this is from the APK that previously worked fine, no changes, but just uploaded to Google Play in the Play Dev Console.

Google themselves were rather useless in helping to solve this issue; providing no direction other than to the docs. Which in turn don't really have any information on why this might occur.

Does anyone here have any ideas on what direction to go in order to fix this?

TL;DR: It seems the game works perfectly fine from the actual APK but does not when obtained from Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is caused by a difference in the SHA1 key given in the API console when compared to the App Signing SHA1 keys.

The once we used was from the app's keystore during development which did not match the active one in the API console.  Changing it fixed all of that.